# Insertion sorting's time complexity in Linked List

Tags: c, time-complexity

```
void nodeinsert(NODE*node, int p){
NODE * new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
new->data = p;
new->next = node->next;
node->next = new;}

void insert_sort_list(NODE*head, int*arr, int num_arr){
NODE *temp;
int i;
insert_node(head, arr[0]);
    for(i = 1; i< num_arr; i++){
        temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            if(temp->next->data < arr[i]){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else{break;}
        }
        nodeinsert(temp, arr[i]);}
```

this is my code for sorting list using Insertion sort.

I heard Insertion sorting's time complexity is O(n^2)
and when I measure sorting time with array using insertion sort, O(n^2)is correct.
But when I measure time for this code it does not look like O(n^2). when n is less than 20000 it is fit to O(n^2) but over 20000 it takes more time. I want to know why does the time complexity look diffrent on list.

Comment: That is the worst-case time complexity. Try ordering them in reverse.

Comment: You cannot reliably confirm/prove time complexity by measuring running times. It is a misunderstanding that is very common. Also, when numbers get high, other effects of your system kick in: greater memory consumption may give the OS more work to do (swapping, ...etc), which may lower the CPU time available to your program. And we know a linked list uses more memory per entry than an array....

Comment: Please use a more orthodox indentation style for C.
I strongly recommend either Allman (which is what I use, more or less)
or some version of 1TBS (which is used by many other people).
See Wikipedia on [Indentation
Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for information
about the variants.

The Pico style, especially with multiple `}` markers on a single line, is anathema in C.

Multiple close braces on a single line is a no-no;
multiple consecutive close braces at the same indent level is another.